# how to use SET_DEBUG_APP permission

Tags: android, permissions

I found the SET_DEBUG_APP permission - it seems to grant permission to do exactly what I need to do at the moment - unfortunately I found no documentation on how to use it - can anybody shed some light on how to use it?

Answer (score 1):

Like any other permission, add it to the AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.somebody.amazing_app" >
        ...
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP" />
        ...
        <application
        ...
        </application>
    ...
</manifest>
```

Most of my devices don't need this; they debug just fine without this line.  But one of my devices insists--it won't start running the app in debug mode without this line.